# Error with BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object" MFC

Tags: c++, menu, mfc, non-static, split-button

I am creating a breakout game using MFC, and now I am programming a level creator. For the user to choose which block is desired to create, I'm using a SplitButton. I have created the menu resource to pair with my SplitButton, but I want each one of the options in the menu to do something. Reading the documentation about how to assign a `afx_msg void OnOptionSelected()` to an event using `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` I found this:

```
//Microsoft Documentation Code
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDoc, CDocument)
ON_COMMAND(ID_MYCMD, &CMyDoc::OnMyCommand)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

And I did the same with my code, creating an `afx_msg` for each of my menu options in my menu resource

```
//My code in CCreateWindow.h (Inside DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP())
afx_msg void OnToughBlockChosen();
afx_msg void OnSturdyBlockChosen();
afx_msg void OnWeakBlockChosen();
afx_msg void OnSpecialBlockChosen();
afx_msg void OnIndestructibleBlockChosen();
```

And thus their assignation

```
//My code in CCreateWindow.cpp (Inside BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP)
ON_COMMAND(ID_CHOOSEBLOCKTYPE_TOUGHBLOCK, &CCreateWindow::OnToughBlockChosen())
ON_COMMAND(ID_CHOOSEBLOCKTYPE_STURDYBLOCK, &CCreateWindow::OnSturdyBlockChosen())
ON_COMMAND(ID_CHOOSEBLOCKTYPE_WEAKBLOCK, &CCreateWindow::OnWeakBlockChosen())
ON_COMMAND(ID_CHOOSEBLOCKTYPE_SPECIALBLOCK, &CCreateWindow::OnSpecialBlockChosen())
ON_COMMAND(ID_CHOOSEBLOCKTYPE_INDESTRUCTIBLEBLOCK, &CCreateWindow::OnIndestructibleBlockChosen())
```

But when I did this, the error `E024 a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object` appears. So far I have an idea of how it can be solved (`ON_COMMAND(ID_CHOOSEBLOCKTYPE_TOUGHBLOCK, &m_CreateWindow.OnToughBlockChosen())`) but just I dunno if that's the way to fix it and if it is I dunno where to declare the object since I tried to do it in the `.h` and `.cpp` and none worked. I just don't know what to do now since I did the same as in the Microsoft Documentation and it explicitly stated:

> The `ON_COMMAND` macro is used to handle command messages generated by menus, buttons, and accelerator keys.

Comment: you will need to remove the paranthesis, such as `&CCreateWindow::OnToughBlockChosen()` should be `&CCreateWindow::OnToughBlockChosen`

Comment: Yeah! That worked. I didn't notice that the documentation code removed the parentheses as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might also want to read this: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html